# thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: failed to resolve sockaddr for host Pyhive and Python

Tags: python, pyhive, sockaddr

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="host", username="hive",auth="NOSASL",port=10000)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I wrote this code.I received this error :

> thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: failed to resolve sockaddr for host.

I use library , tweepy,pyhive

```
pure-sasl==0.6.1
PyHive==0.6.1
pyhs2==0.6.0
pyOpenSSL==17.2.0
PySAL==1.14.4.post1
pysasl==0.4.1
sasl==0.2.1
thrift==0.11.0
tweepy==3.5.0
twitter==1.18.0``
twython==3.7.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host given is wrong. For example, it maybe 'localhost'.